# Enable two submit buttons having same id's by javascript

Tags: javascript, submit

I have two submit buttons having the same name,class, value all are same.

Here i need to enable those two buttons from java script after completing the page loading.

Here one button is enabled another is in disabled state 
Here the buttons code is

```
<input id="SAVE_HEADER" type="submit" value="Next" name="button" class="button"/>
<input id="SAVE_HEADER" type="submit" value="Next" name="button" class="button"/>
```

And here is my java-script code

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () 
{
    alert(document.readyState);

    if(document.readyState == "interactive")
    {
        $("#SAVE_HEADER").each(function() {
            alert("add");
            $("#SAVE_HEADER").attr("disabled");
        });
    }
    if(document.readyState == "complete")
    {   
        $("#SAVE_HEADER").each(function() {
            alert("rem");           
            $("#SAVE_HEADER").removeAttr("disabled");           
        });
    }
}
```

Can anyone help regarding this.

Comment: There should be one Unique id with each element.

Comment: Try giving your buttons class.

Comment: yes your right but here am using "each" function also..

Comment: Instead of using each for the ID's use it for the class. You can't have multiple elements with the same ID, you'll end up having undefined behaviour.

Comment: yeah i did that but not came to enable state. One button in enable mode after this executing this code with class or id but another one is not

Answer (score 0):

There should be one Unique id with each element. Try giving your buttons class.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, using same `id` attribute on two different elements is not valid ([explanatory LINK](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)). Use `class` attr instead of it.

Secondly, try using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library (it's easier to use than plain JavaScript):

HTML:

```
<input id="SAVE_HEADER1" type="submit" value="Next" name="button" class="button"/>
<input id="SAVE_HEADER2" type="submit" value="Next" name="button" class="button"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('input.button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q4ogky5d/

Answer (score 0):

`document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState == "complete") {
        $(".button").each(function(btn) {
           $(btn).removeAttr("disabled")
       });
    }
}`